# My ashx page is returning a body but I only want to send a status code 200

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I've set up an ashx page to receive a webhook notification. However, I'm getting and error from the webhook provider that my response contains a body. For the moment I just want to send a status code of 200. This is my code :-

```
public class updateTS : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see my content does not have a body. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use context.Response.Clear() first to empty the response and set the StatusCode to 200:

```
    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Whatever you're communicating with might be inferring that you have a body because the content type is set. You could try removing the ContentType line completely. If that doesn't work could you share the exact error message please?

Comment: I've tried removing the content type but still the same error. The exact error message is 'Response contained a body'
Unfortunately that's all it gives

Comment: The last thing I can think to suggest is setting Response.SuppressContent = true; this forces only headers to be sent. There's a good comparison of what the output is in each situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995844/when-should-i-set-httpresponse-suppresscontent-to-true

Comment: If possible you should also try and examine the response you're sending using something like Fiddler.

Comment: still no dice, but thanks for your help anyway